# CLLocation to track what road iPhone is on

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, gps, cllocationmanager

I am attempting to make an app (ios 8/ Xcode 6.4/ Swift language) which uses CLLocation. This app requires the speed limit of the current road or highway on which the iPhone is traveling. Is there any way to do this or even just to determine the road? Or possibly if they are within city limits or not? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if much has changed since this: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/675/data-source-for-speed-limits?newreg=cfa560890dc14eabbdbb983282c5e574 - but getting the location data from CLLocation is easy, check out: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/ - You can get the coordinate and then ref. in some speed limit database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depending on what api you use to determine the speed limit on the road you're on, you may need to do **reverse geocoding**. This allows you to get an actual useful address from the `CLLocation` you got from you `CLManager`.

So assuming you have a `location` which is `CLLocation`, something like:

```
let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { placemarks, error in
println("*** Found placemarks: \(placemarks), error: \(error)") })
```

your `placemarks` would contain a `thoroughfare` property which would reference the street.

Take a look at the `CLPlacemark` class reference to see what else is available: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLPlacemark/thoroughfare)